# Golang приведение типов

Tags: golang, приведение-типов

Пишу функцию, которая должна на вход принимать число Uint, удалять нечетные цифры и нули(если входящее число 0, то отдавать ответом 100), после чего, выводить измененное число в этом же формате, то есть в Uint

На данный момент код следующий:

```
fn := func (a uint) uint {
    if a == uint(0) { return uint(100) }
    newA := []rune(strconv.FormatUint(uint64(a), 10))
    var strA string
    for _, elem := range newA {
        if elem % 2 == 0 && elem != '0' {
            strA += string(elem)
        }
    }
    res, err := strconv.ParseUint(strA, 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    a = uint(res)
    return a
}
```

Почему-то код не всегда отрабатывал корректно, решил проверять по действиям, наткнулся на следующую ошибку, никак не могу понять, с чем она связана. Код:

```
func main() {
    var num uint
    fmt.Scan(&num)
    fn := func(a uint) uint {
        if a == 0 {
            return 0
        }
        newA := []rune(strconv.FormatUint(uint64(a), 10))
        fmt.Printf("Type - %T, Num - %c\n", newA, newA)
        return 0
    }
    fn(num)
}
```

При входных данный `000234` в слайс рун `newA` записывается некорректное значение:

```
Output:
000234
Type - []int32, Num - [1 5 6]
```

Думал, какая-то ошибка в приведении `string` к `[]rune`, но нет, убрав приведение типа, вывод тот же

```
newA := strconv.FormatUint(uint64(a), 10)
fmt.Printf("Type - %T, Num - %s\n", newA, newA)   //исправленное
Output:
000234
Type - string, Num - 156
```

Подскажите, почему так получается,  и что можно этому противопоставить?

Comment: Читайте документацию как пользоваться [strconv](https://golangify.com/string-in-number), то чем вы занимаетесь - это typecasting, а не конверсия типов.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov могу ошибаться в терминлогии, но я же попросил объяснить почему так происходит, а не кинуть ссылку на noname-ресурс в котором ничего, по сути, не описано

Comment: А зачем вы пишите ноль в начале?  Числа начинающиеся с нуля считаются записанными в восьмеричной системе https://go.dev/ref/spec#Integer_literals так что 0234 === 156

Comment: @AlexeyTen благодарю, совсем забыл о данном правиле.

Answer (score 1):

Давайте по порядку - у вас на входе строка, в которой есть только цифры, НО строковые цифры (руны) != обычные. Вы строку читаете через fmt.Scan, здесь всё верно.

Дальше согласно описанной вами логике, вам нужно конвертировать строку в число, перед этим удалив нечетные строковые значения.

В итоге код получается следующим:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    var input = ""
    fmt.Printf("Введите данные:")
    _, errRead := fmt.Scanln(&input)
    if errRead != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Ошибка чтения данных из строки: %s", errRead.Error())
        return
    }

    value, errGetValue := GetResult(input)
    if errGetValue != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Ошибка конверсии строки в Uint: %s", errGetValue.Error())
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("Результат: %d\n", value)
}

func GetResult(num string) (uint64, error) {
    var filteredNumbersMap = map[rune]bool{'1': false, '3': false, '5': false, '7': false, '9': false,
        '0': true, '2': true, '4': true, '6': true, '8': true}
    var cleanedUpInput []rune
    // Логика - если руна присутствует в map И её значение = true, то включать её в итоговую строку
    for _, numChar := range num {
        include, mappingExists := filteredNumbersMap[numChar]
        if mappingExists && include {
            cleanedUpInput = append(cleanedUpInput, numChar)
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("Фильтрованный результат (строка): %s\n", string(cleanedUpInput))
    convertedResult, errParse := strconv.ParseUint(string(cleanedUpInput), 10, 64)
    // Если ошибка во время парсинга - возвращаем её
    if errParse != nil {
        return 0, errParse
    }

    if convertedResult == 0 {
        return 100, nil
    }

    return convertedResult, nil
}
```

Comment: По тз число подаётся изначально в формате uint. Не совсем понимаю, зачем здесь использовать map'ы. Однако, ваше решение мне понятно, немного откорректировал под себя, и все работает корректно. Благодарю.